# Pam is unable to make users home directory

Tags: ssh, authentication, gitlab

I have an ubuntu 12.04 LTS server that is tied to Active Directory. This is a git server running gitlab. Rather than using gitolite it uses the gitlab shell

In the logs I notice that every time the 'git' user authenticates, I get the same 11 errors in the /var/log/auth.log

```
May 14 15:06:10 gitlab sshd[14775]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user git by (uid=0)
May 14 15:06:10 gitlab sshd[14775]: pam_mkhomedir(sshd:session): unknown option: skel
May 14 15:06:10 gitlab sshd[14775]: pam_mkhomedir(sshd:session): unknown option: =
May 14 15:06:10 gitlab sshd[14775]: pam_mkhomedir(sshd:session): unknown option: /etc/skel/
May 14 15:06:10 gitlab sshd[14775]: pam_mkhomedir(sshd:session): unknown option: mask=0077
May 14 15:06:10 gitlab sshd[14775]: pam_mkhomedir(sshd:session): unknown option: skel
May 14 15:06:10 gitlab sshd[14775]: pam_mkhomedir(sshd:session): unknown option: =
May 14 15:06:10 gitlab sshd[14775]: pam_mkhomedir(sshd:session): unknown option: /etc/skel/
May 14 15:06:10 gitlab sshd[14775]: pam_mkhomedir(sshd:session): unknown option: mask=0077
May 14 15:06:10 gitlab sshd[14775]: pam_mkhomedir(sshd:session): unknown option: skel
May 14 15:06:10 gitlab sshd[14775]: pam_mkhomedir(sshd:session): unknown option: =
May 14 15:06:10 gitlab sshd[14775]: pam_mkhomedir(sshd:session): unknown option: /etc/skel/
```

The 'git' user already has a home directory.

I'm at a bit of a loss on this one. None of the top hits on google shed any light on the problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

**Update**

I'm pretty new to pam, here are what I think are relevant config files

```
ls /etc/pam.d
atd   chpasswd  common-account  common-password  common-session-noninteractive  login     other   polkit-1  samba  su
chfn  chsh      common-auth     common-session   cron                           newusers  passwd  ppp       sshd   sudo

cat /etc/pam.d/common-session | grep -v '#'
session [default=1]         pam_permit.so
session requisite           pam_deny.so
session required            pam_permit.so
session optional            pam_umask.so
session required    pam_unix.so
session optional                    pam_sss.so
session optional pam_mkhomedir.so skel = /etc/skel/ mask=0077
session optional pam_mkhomedir.so skel = /etc/skel/ mask=0077
session optional pam_mkhomedir.so skel = /etc/skel/ mask=0077
session optional            pam_ck_connector.so nox11


cat /etc/pam.d/sshd | grep -v '#'
@include common-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
@include common-account
@include common-session
session    required     pam_limits.so
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-password
```

Comment: What does the relevant section of your pam config look like?  Please update your question with the relevant bit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `pam_mkhomedir` lines in `/etc/pam.d/common-session`, try `skel=/etc/skel umask=0077` (ie, remove the spaces around the `=` sign after `skel`, and add a `u` before `mask`).

Comment: That worked, except I changed umask to 0022